# Proguard green robot event bus

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, greenrobot-eventbus

I'm using Event bus on my app. following the [docs](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/proguard/) I've added

```
# Green Robot Eventbus
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }
```

to my `<project>/app/proguard-rules.pro`

But when compile my app alsways get the error

```
ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rkmax.myapp.MyActivity}:  org.greenrobot.eventbus.e: Subscriber class com.rkmax.myapp.MyActivity and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation
```

my app is workin fine on debug release. maybe it's something I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All my Subscribe-annotated methods was defined like `void methodName(...)` I found I must explicit add `public` in order to work correctly on releases builds